# HashSet `.ToArray()` using F#

Tags: f#, ienumerable, hashset

What do I need to do to be able to call `.ToArray ()` for a HashSet? I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
let a = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet ()
a.Add 5 |> ignore
a.ToArray () // Not possible
let b = a :> System.Collections.IEnumerable
b.ToArray () // Not possible
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), this is stated:

> ToArray : Creates an array from a IEnumerable. (Defined by Enumerable.)

so there should be a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IEnumerable.ToArray() is defined as an extension method under System.Linq.
Alternatively, use Seq.toArray or Array.ofSeq.

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq

let hs = HashSet()
hs.Add 4
hs.Add 2

let arr = hs.ToArray()       // needs System.Linq
let arr2 = hs |> Seq.toArray // provided by F#
```

Answer (score 3):

The `HashSet` type implements standard generic `IEnumerable<'T>` type (called `seq<'T>` in F#), so you can use `Seq.toArray` (without opening any namespaces):

```
let hs = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet()
hs.Add(1)

let ar = hs |> Seq.toArray
```

Using C# extension method `ToArray` will work too (if you open `System.Linq`), but I believe that using standard F# functions is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an extension method, so you need to open the namespace containing Enumerable (Linq?) to get it, just as in C#.